# How to prevent a value from being generated in a random int? (Java)

Tags: java, android, random

I have two randomly generated variables. LoadG4 is outputted to one button and the other 3 buttons have a differing value for randoms1 generated. My aim here is to ensure that no value of the randomly generated randoms1 is equal to LoadG4. For example if the range is between 0 to 9 and LoadG4 ends up being 3, the other random numbers from randoms1.nextint... must not be 3. They could be 7, 4, or 5 for example, but not the same as LoadG4.

Here's my code:

```
Random GenerateG4 = new Random();
            int loadG4 = GenerateG4.nextInt(10);
            Random randoms1 = new Random();
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(""+loadG4);
            for(int allrbA=0; allrbA<4; allrbA++) {
                selectrb[allrbA].setText(""+randoms1.nextInt(10));
            }
            selectrb[rbselector].setText(""+loadG4);
```

How could I do this?

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATED CODE:

```
if (rbvalue==loadG4) {
                    int realrbvalue = rbvalue++;
                    selectrb[allrbA].setText(""+realrbvalue);
                }
                else {
                    selectrb[allrbA].setText(""+rbvalue);
                }
            }
```

Why does this still not work?

Comment: Generate a number in the range 0-8, and add 1 if that number is greater than or equal to the number you want to avoid.

Comment: 3 was just an example, and that doesn't make much sense to me. How would this work?

Comment: @AndyTurner Please see updated code. Why does that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation of the comment:

```
for(int allrbA=0; allrbA<4; allrbA++) {
   int r = randoms1.nextInt(10 - 1); // range one less because one will be skipped
   if (r == load4G) r = 9;           // don't want this one, take the one
                                     // that would have been included in the full range

   selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + r);
}
```

The comment proposal is to add one to `r` for any random value where `r >= load4G` - this implies that the final value of `r` could never equal load4G - which has the same net effect.

With a loop to re-generate a new random:

```
for(int allrbA=0; allrbA<4; allrbA++) {
   int r; 
   do {
      r = randoms1.nextInt(10);   // get a random number
   } while (r == load4G);         // until it is different

   selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + r);
}
```

If *all* the random numbers must be different a (Fisher-Yates) shuffle would be an appropriate solution.

Comment: What does it mean by r = randoms1.nextInt(10 - 1); and what is that for?

Comment: `nextInt(10 - 9)` returns a random number in the range [0, 9) - eg. a value of 0..1....7..8.

Comment: Why not just r = randoms1.nextInt(10 ); ?

Comment: Because that would return a number in the range [0, 10) - eg. a value of 0..1....9..10. However this leaves no "space" to deal with skipping load4G. Note that the approach with the loop doesn't need to account for this because it tries to get a new random number.

Comment: I don't understand if (r == load4G) r = 9;  either, why set it equal to 9?

Comment: Because a number 0..8 was picked. If this number was load4G (a value of 0..9) then we don't want that one, so we choose 9 (because this is the completing value in the full range to generate, and is not load4G). Walk through the process using a pen and paper.

Comment: Sorry could you please break this down for me? I am struggling to understand what is meant to happen and how this works. Your co-operation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following should put you on the right track. The idea is that for the second extraction we reduce the range by one. If the number extracted is less than the previous extracted, that's good. If not, then we add 1 to it to obtain a number in range [v1+1, n]:

```
Random r = new Random();
int v1 = r.nextInt(n);
int  v2 = r.nextInt(n-1);
if (v2 >= v1)
  v2++
```

Comment: So I have to manually repeat the code for each button and set each value to each button? Not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and just check if new random number is already exist in your array. While you have only loop of 4 steps it will not influence performance, but in this solution **all** numbers will be random.

```
    int arr[] = new int[4];

    for(int allrbA=0; allrbA<4; allrbA++) {

        int num;

        do{
             num = randoms1.nextInt(10);
        }
        while(!Arrays.asList(arr).contains(num));

        arr[allrbA] = num;

    }
```

Comment: To make all random numbers unique - ie. when shuffling a card deck or a keypad keys - consider a (Fisher-Yates) shuffle.